# Streaming avro files from a directory

Tags: apache-spark, avro, spark-structured-streaming, spark-avro

I'm trying to set up a structured stream from a directory of Avro files. We already have some non-streaming code to deal with exact the same data, so the least-effort step forward to streaming would be to re-use that code.

To move to StructuredStreaming, I tried the following, which works in the non-streaming manner (using `read` in stead of `readStream`) but gives me a serialization error in the streaming approach.

```scala
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
import org.apache.avro._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import com.databricks.spark.avro._

val schemaStr = """ {our_schema_here} """

val parser  = new Schema.Parser()
val avroSchema = parser.parse(schemaStr)
val structType = SchemaConverters.toSqlType(avroSchema).dataType match {
      case t: StructType => Some(t)
      case _ => throw new RuntimeException(
        s"""Avro schema cannot be converted to a Spark SQL StructType:
          |
          |${avroSchema.toString(true)}
          |""".stripMargin)
    }

val path = "dbfs://path/to/avro/files/*"

val avroStream = sqlContext
  .readStream
  .schema(structType.get)
  .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 5)
  .load(path)
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .format("memory")
  .queryName("counts")
  .start()
```

The exception I get is shown below. Note, I can't get the full stacktrace as I'm on Databricks and get access the executors logs. I'm a bit at loss what exactly is the object that can't be serialized.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2125)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:937)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:936)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:299)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:291)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2966)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2456)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2456)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$57.apply(Dataset.scala:2950)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2949)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2456)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MemorySink.addBatch(memory.scala:217)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:731)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:731)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:731)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:730)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:730)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:730)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch(StreamExecution.scala:729)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:328)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:312)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:226)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.collection.immutable.MapLike$$anon$1
Serialization stack:

at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
... 41 more
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683513/bertjan-broeksema : Did you found the solution for this yet ?

Comment: Nope, and I switched context so I didn't work on it either. I still think it's an interesting issue though :).